# Update only one column in mysql table using sqoop

Tags: sqoop

I have a mysql table with 5 columns(a,b,c,d,e) with "a" being the primary key. And I have a csv file containing values for only "a" & "d" columns. I want to update the values for only one column "d" based on values of "a" present in the file. Is this can be achieved using sqoop? If my csv file has all the column's data then I am able to export the data from my csv file to the table and update all the rows using "--update-key" as "a". Is it possible to update only one column's data?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no direct command to do that. However the possible solution is to create a MySQL temp table with two columns "a" and "d", load the data using sqoop (two columns only "a" and "d") to the temp table and then do join between MySQL temp table and final table to update the specific column.